# Get TFS Query GUID

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-sdk

I am using some existing code in a project where some code is querying using a GUID to get list of WorkItems from a query ( as list of blocking bugs etc.) using a query name and GUID.

var items = project.Store.GetQueryDefinition(queryGUID);

**Question : for a given TFS query how can I get its GUID ?**